# How can I await inside the builder function of FutureBuilder Widget - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am trying to retrieve data from the firebase twice inside the FutureBuilder, first time the 'future:' parameter takes care of retrieving the data. However, the second time when I try to retrieve 'restaurant' data from firebase, I am getting a null error because I can't wait for the 'getRestauran()' function to finish executing. If I add 'await' before the function it gives an error because 'async' can't be applied to the 'builder' function.

Is there a way to make this work?

```
Future<Restaurant> getRestaurant(String restaurantId) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> restaurantData;
    String id;
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('restaurants')
        .doc(restaurantId)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      restaurantData = value.data();
      id = value.id;
    });
    print(restaurantData);
    final restaurant1 = Restaurant(
      id: id,
      name: restaurantData['name'],
      description: restaurantData['description'],
      // cuisine: List<String>.from(restaurant['cuisine']),
      imageUrl: restaurantData['imageUrl'],
      isAvailable: restaurantData['isAvailable'],
      isFavourite: restaurantData['isFavourite'],
      pickupTime: restaurantData['pickupTime'].toDate(),
      stars: restaurantData['stars'].toDouble(),
      location: Location(
        address: restaurantData['location']['address'],
        city: restaurantData['location']['city'],
        latitude: restaurantData['location']['latitude'],
        longitude: restaurantData['location']['longitude'],
        zipcode: restaurantData['location']['zipcode'],
        locality: restaurantData['location']['locality'],
      ),
      // items: restItems,
      // reviews: reviews,
    );
    return restaurant1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    final order = Provider.of<Order>(context);
    // cartItems =
    //     Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false).cartItems.values.toList();
    //print(cartItems[0].title);
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body:
          // cartItems.isEmpty
          //     ? Center(
          //         child: Text(
          //           'Your Cart is Empty',
          //           style: TextStyle(
          //             color: kTextLightColor,
          //             fontSize: 18,
          //           ),
          //         ),
          //       )
          // :
          FutureBuilder<List<CartItem>>(
              future: cart.fetchCartItems(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('loading');
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }

                List<CartItem> cartItems = snapshot.data;
                print(cartItems[0].restaurantId);
                Map<String, dynamic> restaurantData;
                String id;
                
                restaurant = getRestaurant(cartItems[0].restaurantId);
                
                print('$restaurant: Restaurant Data');
                // return isComplete
                return CartWidget(
                    restaurant: restaurant,
                    cart: cart,
                    cartItems: cartItems,
                    order: order);
                // : CircularProgressIndicator();
              }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can't `await` inside build methods. You can invoke functions, but you can't await for them. Future builder solves this issue.

In your case, you need two future builders, and you have the first one figured out.

```
The solution is to go to your `CartWidget`, when you define it, add a required string to it like this, instead of requiring a `restaurant` object, you require a `restaurantId`:

class CartWidget extends StatelessWidget{
final String restaurantId;
const CartWidget({required this.restaurantId});
//.
//.
// the rest of your widget logic, also move this function completely to this widget
//Future<Restaurant> getRestaurant(String restaurantId) async {}
}
```

Then, inside your build, when it comes to restaurant, use a future builder, and get it using the function you moved here. It will solve your problem.

Comment: it is not a good solution to chain `FutureBuilder`s - instead you should chain your `Future`s in one `async` method - what if you had a chain with 3 or more nested `Future`s? would you use 3 or more nested `FutureBuilder`s?

Comment: Can you point out the problem in chaining F.Builders? What's wrong with chaining them together, but makes it okay for chaining the async functions to build them? It actually gives finer control over what is being displayed on the screen, and doesn't overFetch data, especially when it comes to firebase when every request matters. That is what F.Builders where made for, and you don't have to wait for all the functions to complete. Whatever completes, gets displayed on the screen. Please provide your arguments, I'm interested in your point of you and ready to change mine if you can prove a point

Comment: I am new to flutter, so I don't have much knowledge about this lol. I was thinking about saving requests and what you say also makes sense, that's why I was planning to include restaurant info. in my cart collection. But if you can provide me with a better solution that saves the number of reads and writes in firebase I would really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: ok take a `sqflite` package for example and imagine that it should show the data based on the previous session (for example your app shows some ebook and in the previous session you stored in the `shared_preferences` the ebook path (ebooks are distributed as sqlite db for fast text searching) and the page number where you stopped reading)

Comment: [continued...] so you have first to read those shared preferences which gets you a book path and page number - this is `Future` "one", then based on that you have to open that sqlite database - this is `Future` "two" and finally when you have that database you read the content from the last read page - this is a `Future` "three" - now would you really create 3 `FutureBuilder`s? or you just do `await shared_prefs` followed by `await open_db` followed by `await readContent` - all of them in one `async` method